# How to get the main Activity class of the parent package?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I created a library. It will be attached to different projects. I need to reference the main activity of the current application inside my library class (this application hosts my library). It is possible without generating a cycle in the results of `getPackageManager()`?

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name, thanks for edit my question

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "main Activity class" in Android. You most likely mean Activity that is referenced in in your AndroidManifest file along the `intent-filter` used by launchers. It can be one of such. It can be none. It can be many in single app. Use `PackageManager` to get them

**EDIT**

> How 'android os' know that of activities is first to visible when I
>   launch any appliction

You set it in manifest file. Any activity with:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

can be your entry point. Usually it's just one per app, but you can have as many as you like.

Comment: How 'android os' know that of activities is first to visible when I launch any appliction?

Comment: If case: activities with 'android.intent.action.MAIN' more thaт one system launch the first (in order in Manifest file) of them or random?

Comment: neither. It will launch exactly the the one you tapped icon of in your launcher. If you do not specify different icon it will use app icon but you can set different one for each activity. This is how i.e. Google Maps and Navigation is done. It's one app with two different entry points.

Comment: I try use 'PackageManager': PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( ApplicationName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES); for( ActivityInfo activity : info.activities) {}
How I can get attribute what activity is have necessary action (android.intent.action.MAIN) and category (android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your library project is set up as a library:

Go to Project Properties -> Android and be sure "Is Library" is checked.

Now, you need to reference your library project in your other project:

Go to Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects.  Click 'Add' and select your library.

You may need to clean the project(s), especially after you make changes to the library project.

Comment: My question is not about add my library in projects. My question how get inside my library a main activity context of application which use my library.

Comment: If all you need is the context, just pass it as a parameter in your constructor of the library class that needs the context.  You can use getBaseContext() to get the activity's context or getApplicationContext() to get the application's context when you create the object from your library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your library(i.e com.example) should be "isLibrary" in Eclipse or "is Library Module" in Android Studio.
2. In order to call any component in library from your "upper project", you can directly call "com.example.component". i.e 
   Intent i = new Intent(this, com.example.component.class);
3. Fellow what @lifeson106 has written in Eclipse. In Android Studio you need another tutorial.

Comment: Library dont know which package include it. And inside library I can't directly call 'com.example.component'.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna "library" to call a component of a project(any one, who uses your library or not), you must define "intent-filter" for your component. Here is a common way for an Activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.gmail.app.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.gmail.app.SplashActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In your codes(library) you could do like that:

```
    Intent i = new Intent("com.gmail.app.SplashActivity");
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: 'SplashActivity' not include in my library. This activity inside in application which use my library. And my library not exist a activity with name 'SplashActivity'.

Comment: @Tapa Save The XML I wrote should be in Mainifast of you project, not in your library.

Comment: Project is not my. It is alient for my library. And I don't know what is in his Manifest file!